How can I retrieve the current duration from the Media Player to display on the song progress bar?
I have tried every possible step but only giving value once, I want it should update every single second. This is my code, what am I doing wrong?
I want to implement progress slider for musics, can anyone please help me?
I'm using a slider library which you this library accept range from current position to total duration.
data class MusicPlayerStates(
    var playingSongCurrentPosition: MutableState<Int> = mutableIntStateOf(0),
    var playingSongDuration: MutableState<Int> = mutableIntStateOf(0),
    
    //other code
)

fun onEvent(event: MusicPlayerUiEvents) {
        when (event) {

            is MusicPlayerUiEvents.PlaySong -> {
                mediaPlayer?.let {
                    if (it.isPlaying) {
                        mediaPlayer?.stop()
                        mediaPlayer?.reset()
                        _musicPlayerState.update { state ->
                            state.copy(
                                playingSongCurrentPosition = state.playingSongCurrentPosition.apply {
                                    this.value = 0
                                },
                                playingSongDuration = state.playingSongDuration.apply {
                                    this.value = 0
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
                _musicPlayerState.update {
                    it.copy(
                        isSongPlaying = it.isSongPlaying.apply {
                            this.value = true
                        }
                    )
                }
                mediaPlayer?.release()
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer().apply {
                    setDataSource(event.url)
                    prepareAsync()
                }
                mediaPlayer?.setOnPreparedListener { mediaPlayer ->
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(state.value.playingSongCurrentPosition.value)
                    mediaPlayer.start()
                    setSongDuration(mediaPlayer.duration)
                    updatePlaybackState(mediaPlayer.currentPosition)
                    
               Log.d("check for currentD_VM","${state.value.playingSongCurrentPosition.value}")
                }

                mediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener { mediaPlayer ->
                    // Use for precise updates
                    mediaPlayer?.stop()
                    _musicPlayerState.update { state ->
                        state.copy(
                            playingSongCurrentPosition = state.playingSongCurrentPosition.apply {
                                this.value = 0
                            },
                            playingSongDuration = state.playingSongDuration.apply {
                                this.value = 0
                            },
                            isSongPlaying = state.isSongPlaying.apply {
                                this.value = false
                            },
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun updatePlaybackState(currentPosition: Int) {
        _musicPlayerState.update {
            it.copy(
                playingSongCurrentPosition = it.playingSongCurrentPosition.apply {
                    this.value = currentPosition
                }
            )
        }
    }

    private fun setSongDuration(duration: Int) {
        _musicPlayerState.update {
            it.copy(
                playingSongDuration = it.playingSongDuration.apply {
                    this.value = duration
                }
            )
        }
    }

 Box(
            modifier =
            Modifier
                .padding(vertical = 80.dp, horizontal = 20.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(20.dp)
        ) {
            var fraction by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(1f) }
            WavySlider(
                valueRange = 1000f..state.playingSongDuration.value.toFloat(),
                value = 1000f,
                onValueChange = { },
                waveLength = 25.dp,     // Set this to 0.dp to get a regular Slider
                waveHeight = 10.dp,     // Set this to 0.dp to get a regular Slider
                waveVelocity = 15.dp to WaveDirection.HEAD, // Speed per second and its direction
                waveThickness = 4.dp,   // Defaults to the specified trackThickness
                trackThickness = 4.dp,  // Defaults to 4.dp, same as regular Slider
                incremental = false,    // Whether to gradually increase waveHeight
                // animationSpecs = ... // Customize various animations of the wave
            )
        }




i want it should update every single second

In order to do this, you must implement some kind of asynchronous loop, using a Coroutine, or Handler, to update the state on an interval using delay() if using a Coroutine or postDelayed() if using a Handler. You can get the exact position of the MediaPlayer using getCurrentPosition()
Here is some example code in Kotlin using a Coroutine
private suspend fun seekbarUpdateObserver() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        while (true) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying) {
                val pos = mediaPlayer!!.currentPosition
                val progress = (pos.toFloat() / mediaPlayer!!.duration) * 100f
                // TODO update SeekBar with progress
            }

            delay(17L)
        }
    }
}

I would recommend an interval of every 17 milliseconds to achieve 60 fps as 1000 ms / 60 ms = ~17 ms
This function can then be called after start using scope.launch()
 private var scope = MainScope()
 // ...
 mediaPlayer!!.start()
 scope.launch { seekbarUpdateObserver() }

and cancelled using the scope.cancel() function
mediaPlayer!!.stop()
mediaPlayer!!.release()
mediaPlayer = null
scope.cancel()


It looks like you are setting the value of the slider to a fixed value of 1000f, this will keep the slider value fixed at 1000f.
In your WavySlider set the value as,
WavySlider(
    valueRange = 0f..state.playingSongDuration.value.toFloat(),
    value = state.playingSongCurrentPosition.value.toFloat(),

here your slider value is updated dynamically according to the current position of the music playback.

Is my view model code right? When i log cat the value it's showing the value once even in ui layer so how it will update the progress bar?Log.d("check for currentD_VM","${state.value.playingSongCurrentPosition.value}"

Your view model seems to be correct and If the log is only displaying the value once and not updating continuously as the song progresses. Check If the UI is observing the changes, if not, it won't update when the state changes.

I didn't understand what you mean about this line (if not, it won't update when the state changes.)
